# Using server-fetched DTO data in WPF MVVM views that don't necessarily resemble DTOs

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel, dto

I am at the beginning of a WPF MVVM project that uses MVVM Light Toolkit. My services in the client consume some external Restful APIs.

Here is my general plan so far for transferring server data to view, and I want to know if it needs to change:

I will create some DTO classes in my project that completely resemble what I will get from the API and name them like `EntityName` and as I get data from API I fill them with fetched data using `JsonConvert`. Also for classes in my `View` or better say my classes to be used in `ViewModel` I will create some view specific classes and name them like `EntityNameSketch` that should inherit from their DTO counterpart and have some calculated additional properties e.g. `FullName` or some UI specific ones like `IsSelected`.

Now a few difficulties:

1. In MVVM Light, Model classes should inherit from `ObservableObject`, making it impossible for me to inherit from my DTO and `ObservableObject` in the same time.
2. If I choose not to inherit from my DTO and go for a completely separate class that will be populated by some converting logic I create for every DTO type, will not it add an extra step in the way of retrieved server data to the view? I mean normally the `JsonConvert` suffices, but in this case I will need an additional converter.

I am open to any suggestions, as dramatically different from mine as they may seem! I just want to make sure what would be the best approach in this regard in terms of efficiency and project structure logic, so when my project grows pretty large (and hell it will) I don't face any additional problems.

**UPDATE:**
I came up with another solution: Having just one class that has DTO's properties and also some desired additional properties, and make `JsonConvert` ignore the added properties. And for clarity's sake I put additional properties in a partial class. However it still has the problem of "DTOs with Observability" which I think shouldn't happen because DTOs are DTOs! and shouldn't care about views.

Comment: What is your DTO? You dont you try to derive your DTO from oservablobject and use it.

Comment: As I've stated in my question, my view object is different from DTO object and I can't use my DTO in my view unless I add many props to it.

Comment: You can derive the DTO from ObservableObject and then you can derive your model from DTO.

Comment: Yeah, that is one possible solution, however I don't see why DTO should inherit from ObservableObject. You know, it is DTO! In my opinion, it shouldn't care about "Observability" which is a view-specific concept. I feel there should be a more elegant and meaningful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "updated" solution works just fine but the problem is that you are actually making your service layer dependent to your view. The solution I suggest is that you have some DTO's in your service that resemble your API objects and have some view-specific objects that are designed to answer the needs of your view which in many cases have almost all of the DTO properties and more. Then one possible approach would be to have some [factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C.23) for your view-specific objects and name them like "ViewObject.Create". In the `Create` method then you accept an interface of your DTO and any other paramters needed and by using a library like "[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)" perform your view-specific object creation logic. With this approach your service layer is completely unaware of your views, which is a very good practice.